# Language changes when pressing Shift+Space (Windows 7 Ultimate K)

Tags: windows-7, windows, language

I have recently bought a Windows 7 Ultimate K, and changed it's language pack and such to English. I have two languages (Korean and English) I use on my computer and whenever I press SHIFT+SPACE it changes it. This really bothers me because when I type I hold the shift and space button... A LOT (Changed language when writing "A LOT":P).This also makes gameplay on ANY game with a sprint+jump sequence VERY DIFFICULT. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To access the settings for the language bar, you can either

  1. Go to `Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages`, then click `Change Keyboards`
  2. Click on the drop-down menu at the bottom right of the language bar and choose `settings`.
- Once you have the settings open, go to the `Advanced Key Settings` tab.
- In the section `Hot keys for input languages`, choose the action that has <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> assigned as its key sequence (probably `Between input languages`). Click `Change Key Sequence` to change the hotkey.
- You can either choose a new hotkey or disable hotkey switching by choosing `Not assigned`.
- There are a limited number of possibilities allowed for hotkeys. If none of the choices for `Between input languages` hotkeys suit you, you could also disable the switching hotkey and assign individual hotkeys to each language instead (using the entries `To English` and `To Korean`). There are more possibilities allowed for these hotkeys (at least on the version of Windows 7 on my laptop).

#### Update

Ah, okay. I noticed that the hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> wasn't available to me, but I thought it might be just a different version of Windows 7.

I wonder if you only have one input method installed and the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> hotkey is defined *within* it to change the character set. Okay...

- On the `Text Services and Input Languages` window (that you get when you click `Change Keyboards`),  look under `Installed services`.

  - Is there only one entry? Is it Korean?
  - It should have a subheading `Keyboard` beneath it. Under that should be a subentry listing an IDE. What does it say?
  - Right click the IME and choose `properties` and look around. Do you see the hotkey?

Comment: When I go to hot keys for input languages, everything is disabled. When I go see to if it's a glitch, there is no setting for Shit+Space, just ctrl+shift, left alt+shift and grave accent ().

Comment: Ah, okay. I noticed that hotkey wasn't listed in my settings, but I thought it might be just a different version of Windows 7. I've updated my answer, try what it says at the end.

Comment: Never mind! I messed with it after it didn't show any hotkey settings and noticed there were 3 Korean settings. I picked the best one and realized that the problem was fixed! Thanks for the help!